# Restrict the trigger of the sidebar cart when clicking "quick add to cart" button

Tags: php, popup, shopify, liquid, cart

I'm a beginner Shopify developer, and I'm facing an issue with our Shopify-powered website. On every product image, there are "quick add to cart" buttons, and when clicked, a popup sidebar cart opens automatically. I've identified that the function responsible for triggering the sidebar cart is onQuickBuyButtonClicked, which is located in the custom.js file. (Prestige theme)

I want to prevent the sidebar cart from opening automatically when the user clicks the "quick add to cart" button. I've tried modifying the code below, but I haven't been successful:

```
    // add product with size swatches js
function onQuickBuyButtonClicked(id, pro_id) {
    const CartCount = document.getElementsByClassName('Header__CartCount')[0];

    $(".loader_" + id).addClass("add-success--adding");
    const product = {
        id: id,
        quantity: 1
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/cart/add.js',
        data: JSON.stringify(product),
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        success: function(cart) {
            setTimeout(function() {
               $(".loader_" + id).removeClass("add-success--adding");
                $(".loader_" + id).addClass("add-success--added");
              cartRecommended(pro_id);
            }, 500);

            setTimeout(function() {
                document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('product:added', {
                    bubbles: true,
                    detail: {
                        variant: cart,
                        quantity: 1
                    }
                }));
            }, 1200);

            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".loader_" + id).removeClass("add-success--adding").removeClass("add-success--added");
              
            }, 1600);
          setTimeout(function() {
          $('#backdrop').addClass('backdrop_active');
          }, 2000);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown) {
            $(".loader_" + id).removeClass("add-success--adding");

            var r = jQuery.parseJSON(errorThrown.responseText);
            $(".error_" + pro_id).html("Error: " + r.description).show();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".error_" + pro_id).html("").hide(100);
            }, 3000);
        }
    });
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

comment on this part of the code from your custom code.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('product:added', {
      bubbles: true,
        detail: {
           variant: cart,
           quantity: 1
        }
      }));
}, 1200);
```

This trigger the sidebar cart after success addition of the product.